# Change password script works but doesn't write correct password into database

Tags: php, mysql, hash, salt

I have this script for change password :

```
<?php
/*
Page/Script Created by Shawn Holderfield
*/

//Establish output variable - For displaying Error Messages
$msg = "";

//Check to see if the form has been submitted
if (mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['submit'])):

    //Establish Post form variables
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
    $npassword = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['npassword']));
    $rpassword = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['rpassword']));

    //Connect to the Database Server
    mysql_connect("mysql..", "", "")or die(mysql_error());

    // Connect to the database
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());

    // Query the database - To find which user we're working with
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username' ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    //Gather database information
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

        $username == $rows['username'];
        $password == $rows['password'];


    endwhile;

    //Validate The Form
    if (empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($npassword) || empty($rpassword)):

        $msg = "All fields are required";

    elseif ($numrows == 0):

        $msg = "This username does not exist";

    elseif ($password != $password):

        $msg = "The CURRENT password you entered is incorrect.";

    elseif ($npassword != $rpassword):

        $msg = "Your new passwords do not match";

    elseif ($npassword == $password):

        $msg = "Your new password cannot match your old password";

    else:

        //$msg = "Your Password has been changed.";
        mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password = '$npassword' WHERE username = '$username'");



        endif;
endif;

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Change Password</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Username: </td>
                        <td><input type="TEXT" name="username" value=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Current Password: </td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" value=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">New Password: </td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="npassword" value=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Repeat New Password: </td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="rpassword" value=""/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change Password"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        <br>
<?php echo $msg; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This actually works fine, access databse and overwrite the current password, but it does not hash the password like while registration 
Registration process script:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }

    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }

    // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //

    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

   // check existing email  
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this email address already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
        }
                $stmt->close();
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error Line 39</p>';
                $stmt->close();
    }

    // check existing username
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

                if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                        // A user with this username already exists
                        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already exists</p>';
                        $stmt->close();
                }
                $stmt->close();
        } else {
                $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error line 55</p>';
                $stmt->close();
        }

    // TODO: 
    // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
    // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
    // perform the operation.

    if (empty($error_msg)) {
        // Create a random salt
        //$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE)); // Did not work
        $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

        // Create salted password 
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password, salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
        header('Location: ./continue.php');
    }
}
?>
```

What can I do to fix this? I want the password that is changed to be in format like while registration. Because now, when I change password, it's hashed but not + salted so it doesnt work when logging in with new password.

EDIT:
Here is login script:

```
<?php
include_once 'psl-config.php';

function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password 
        FROM members
       WHERE email = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password );
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password
        $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 

            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
function checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) {
    // Get timestamp of current time 
    $now = time();

    // All login attempts are counted from the past 2 hours. 
    $valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time 
                             FROM login_attempts 
                             WHERE user_id = ? 
                            AND time > '$valid_attempts'")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);

        // Execute the prepared query. 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        // If there have been more than 5 failed logins 
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 5) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
function login_check($mysqli) {
    // Check if all session variables are set 
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], 
            $_SESSION['email'],
                        $_SESSION['username'], 
                        $_SESSION['login_string'])) {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password 
                                      FROM members 
                                      WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            // Bind "$user_id" to parameter. 
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                // If the user exists get variables from result.
                $stmt->bind_result($password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                if ($login_check == $login_string) {
                    // Logged In!!!! 
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Not logged in 
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Not logged in 
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Not logged in 
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Not logged in 
        return false;
    }
}
function esc_url($url) {

    if ('' == $url) {
        return $url;
    }

    $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);

    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
    $url = (string) $url;

    $count = 1;
    while ($count) {
        $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url, $count);
    }

    $url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);

    $url = htmlentities($url);

    $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&#038;', $url);
    $url = str_replace("'", '&#039;', $url);

    if ($url[0] !== '/') {
        // We're only interested in relative links from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
        return '';
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, why can't you write a function to encrypt the password and use it in both pages (registration & update password) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and the [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function, MD5 or sha512 are *not* appropriate to hash passwords, because they are ways too fast and can be brute-forced too easily. The password_hash function will generate the salt on its own, you won't need an extra field in the database to store it.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Note: Using the password_hash function, there is no need to escape the password with mysql_real_escape_string, just use the original user entry.

**Edit:**

So i will try to point out some problems in your code, to be honest it looks a bit strange. I would try to start anew and use PDO or mysqli instead of the mysql functions, this would make it easier to protect against SQL-injection.

### Change-password script

One problem is that you reuse the $password variable, which leads to the wrong comparison, though because you used == instead of = it does nothing:

```
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
...
$password == $rows['password'];
...
elseif ($password != $password):
  $msg = "The CURRENT password you entered is incorrect.";
```

I myself spend a lot of time to find descriptive variable names, this helps to prevent such mistakes.

```
$oldPassword = $_POST['password'];
...
$passwordHashFromDb = $rows['password'];
...
elseif (!password_verify($oldPassword, $passwordHashFromDb))
  $msg = "The CURRENT password you entered is incorrect.";
```

Then before you store the new password in the database you calculate the hash:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$newPassword = $_POST['npassword'];
...
$newPasswordHash = password_hash($newPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password = '$newPasswordHash' WHERE username = '$username'");
```

### Registration-script

In your registration script there are other problems, surely you don't expect the user to enter a 128 character password?

```
if (strlen($password) != 128) { // looks strange to me
```

Instead of using a different hash algo, you should use the same as above:

```
// Create salted password 
$passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Insert the new user into the database 
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
  $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $passwordHash);
...
```

### Login-script

In your login script you check whether the password matches the password stored in the database.

```
if ($db_password == $password) {
  // Password is correct!
```

There you should test the hash like this:

```
if (password_verify($password, $db_password) {
  // Password is correct!
```

The call to the password_hash() function does not help in a login script and should be removed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand... Where I have to write it? where I have to use it for?

Comment: @Steven - Whenever you store a password, in the registration form and in the password change form, you can take the user input and call this function, e.g. `$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($_POST['npassword'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`. The variable `$hashToStoreInDb` can then be stored in the database. When you have to check the password, in the login form and in the password change form (old password), then you read the stored hash from the database and call `$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($_POST['password'], $existingHashFromDb)`.

Comment: I think i got it but... Could you show me in example code how should it look? I have no idea what should I remove and what add.

Comment: @Steven - Ok i tried to give some examples with your code, but there is a lot more we could discuss about the code. Maybe it would be easier to start anew. I would switch to prepared statements as you did in your second script, then you could avoid the `mysql_real_escape_string` and all the `md5`, escaping should be done as late as possible and only when necessary.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Going to try it, and if I'll have any problems, would you please correct me?

Comment: Wait... Do I have to overwrite all $password to $passwordHash?

Comment: @Steven - No, the idea is to use different variables for different things, assign the user-input into variable `$password` and the calculated hash into variable `$passwordHash`. This is just a good habit, you immediately can see what's inside and cannot mix it up. Your second script would actually work as you wrote it, with only the `$password` variable, but in your first script you mixed them up because of the variablename. First you assigned the user-input, afterwards you tried to assign the hash from the database to the same variable, with good names you hadn't mixed them up.

Comment: I tried this login code (look edit), but it doesnt work.. why?

Comment: @Steven - You never used the `$passwordHash`variable. This is your third script the login script, so you would need the `password_verify()` function. Instead of line `if ($db_password == $password)` you should write `if (password_verify($password, $db_password))`. Of course the register script must first create and store such a hash with the `password_hash()` function (instead of the SHA).

Comment: So... how does the function login check should look like? Because I overwrited that sha to password_hash but it gave me error :
"password_hash() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /..."

Comment: @Steven - Please have a look at my first example in the answer.

Comment: I don' know which one you mean... There is only that one for storing password and change password/registration.. I want to check if user is logged in.

Comment: @Steven - Ok i made an edit to my answer, including the login script.

Comment: @martinsteockli - Login now works fine, everything is clearly perfect. But.. how do I check if user is logged in ? on a page, I have this script to check if user is logged , and if not, it won't display the information for the logged user - code - <?php if(login_check($mysqli) == true){ ?> the "login_check" function is included in my post. Could you please tell me what to do?

Comment: @Steven - In the login script you already set `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;`, so you can just check whether this variable is set or not: `$isLoggedIn = isset($_SESSION['user_id'])`. Look for a tutorial if you need help with your session, and don't forget to call the `session_start()` function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to check i through that $isLoggedIn :/

Comment: @Steven - This is just a variable, you could also write it like this: `if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { // user is logged in } else { // user is not logged in }`.

Comment: You sir, you are my hero! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are some more comments in the modified code. Here is how you should do it.
Get the old salt from your database

```
//Gather database information
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

    $username = $rows['username']; //single equals to assign value
    $password = $rows['password']; 
    $user_salt = $rows['salt']; // here get old salt

endwhile;
```

and this part to read and use the old salt

```
else:

    //$msg = "Your Password has been changed."; 
  $salted_password = hash('sha512', $npassword . $user_salt);// here use old salt  
 mysql_query("UPDATE members SET password = '$salted_password' WHERE username = '$username'");


endif;
```